# python office365 Sharepoint API filter on navigation property

Tags: python, office365-rest-client

I have been struggling with what seems a simple thing to do but yet I cant find any help online about nor in the official site for the python office 365 rest api site:

https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/blob/master/examples/sharepoint/listitems/filter.py

Basically Im trying to read document library as list items which works fine and I get the files as list item where each item has a file object containing file info and properties. I even managed to get file properties using expand like this:

```
items = large_list.get_items().expand(["File/Name","File/ModifiedBy"]).get()
```

However when I tried to apply filter on the file name like this :

```
large_list.get_items().expand(["File/Name","File/ModifiedBy"]).filter("File/Name ne 'Banner.png'").get()
```

I keep getting error stating the File column doesnt exist ! I thought with OData you can filter using navigation properties so what am I doing wrong here.
Please advise.
Thanks